# registerAidsForService is new NFC feature added in Android 5.0 not working

Tags: android, nfc, android-5.0-lollipop

Need to have both static AID's and Dynamic AID's

Code below executes and dynamicAIDList loads with AID's from list

However when cardEmulation2.registerAidsForService runs it always returns false

indicating that the AID's were not added and cardEmulation2.getAidsForService returns null indicating the AID's were not loaded

Since code loads but does not build and AID's what am I doing wrong?

Here is code:

```
    ComponentName myName = this.getComponentName(); 
    boolean aidStat = false;
    NfcAdapter adapter2 = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    CardEmulation cardEmulation2 = CardEmulation.getInstance(adapter2);
    dynamicAIDList = Arrays.asList("A0000000031010", "A0000000041010", "A00000002501");
    aidStat = cardEmulation2.registerAidsForService (myName, "payment", dynamicAIDList);
    //appAIDComponent

    dynamicAIDList = cardEmulation2.getAidsForService(myName, "payment");
```

Manifest setting 1 tried where aid_list contains static AID's:

```
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service" android:resource="@xml/aid_list" />
```

Manifest setting 2 tried where aid_list contains no AID's and is place holder for AID structure:

```
            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service" android:resource="@xml/apduservice"/>
```

Comment: Do you call the above code from within the service? How is your service component registered in the manifest?

Comment: No, this is an experimental code snippet that I put in the apps "On Create" section just to test and debug the ability to use these new NFC features. I am loading the AID's from a static xml and will be replacing that with a dynamic load of the AID's from a file read but have not determined where to locate the logic to do this yet.

Comment: <service android:name="com.verifone.VANTA.HostCardEmulationService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service" android:resource="@xml/aid_list" />
            
       </service>

Comment: @MichaelRoland which should be the best approach to use `registerAidsForService` method invocation? If the user or Android kills the app, the one of the XML @xml/apduservice will be restored loosing the dynamic ones that `registerAidsForService` method set.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with my code. The line:    ComponentName myName = this.getComponentName(); is incorrect and points to the wrong component it should have been:

```
    ComponentName myComponentName = new ComponentName(this, HostCardEmulationService.class);
```

Once I restructured the Component name to be the correct and point to the HostCardEmulationService.class I was able to dynamically add the AID's.

Note I changed the label myName to myComponentName to make the code more understandable.